# Error with XSL File in c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xslt

With the code, I get the error . I am trying to to a Transform using an xml and this xsl file. Please assist/advise. Deleted a few line to make it easier. Really trying to understand why I get this error even though I make changes.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression StateError   Stylesheet must start either with an 'xsl:stylesheet' or an 'xsl:transform' element, or with a literal result element that has an 'xsl:version' attribute, where prefix 'xsl' denotes the 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' namespace.
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/">

<SCRIPT>
    <xsl:comment>
        <![CDATA[
    function sort(field)
    {
      sortField.value = field;
      <!-- set cursor to watch here? -->
      listing.innerHTML = source.documentElement.transformNode(stylesheet);
    }
  ]]>
    </xsl:comment>
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT for="window" event="onload">
    <xsl:comment>
        <![CDATA[
    stylesheet = document.XSLDocument;
    source = document.XMLDocument;
    sortField = document.XSLDocument.selectSingleNode("//@order-by");
  ]]>
    </xsl:comment>
</SCRIPT>
<HTML>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"></META>
<BODY>
    <xsl:for-each select="report/titledata">
        <table width="80%" border="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%">
                    <div align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma">
                            <b>
                                <font size="3">
                                    <xsl:if match=".[title=1]">
                                        INCOMING REPORT
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if match=".[title=2]">
                                        OUTGOING REPORT
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </font>
                            </b>
                        </font>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="25%" >
                    <div align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="2">
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
                            </b>
                        </font>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="25%">
                    <div align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="2">
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="time"/>
                            </b>
                        </font>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:if match=".[subtitle=1]">
                        <div align="center">
                            <font face="tahoma">
                                <b>
                                    <font size="2">FROM CORPORATE CLIENT</font>
                                </b>
                            </font>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if match=".[subtitle=2]">
                        <div align="center">
                            <font face="tahoma">
                                <b>
                                    <font size="2">FROM ACH</font>
                                </b>
                            </font>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if match=".[subtitle=3]">
                        <div align="center">
                            <font face="tahoma">
                                <b>
                                    <font size="2">TO LOCAL ENTITIES</font>
                                </b>
                            </font>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if match=".[subtitle=4]">
                        <div align="center">
                            <font face="tahoma">
                                <b>
                                    <font size="2">TO ACH</font>
                                </b>
                            </font>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:if>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <br></br>
    <xsl:for-each select="report/file">
        <xsl:if match=".[viewFile=1]">
            <table width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <font face="Tahoma" size="3" color="#000000">
                            <b>File Header Information</b>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <font face="Tahoma" size="3" color="#000000">
                            <b>File Control Information</b>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="16%">
                        <font color="#000000">
                            <b>
                                <font face="Tahoma" size="2">Id:</font>
                            </b>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="36%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <font face="Tahoma" size="2" color="#000000">
                            <xsl:value-of select="filecons"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="20%">
                        <font color="#000000">
                            <b>
                                <font face="Tahoma" size="2">Debit Total:</font>
                            </b>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="28%"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="16%">
                        <font color="#000000">
                            <b>
                                <font face="Tahoma" size="2">Date and Time:</font>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="location"/></table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</BODY>
 </HTML>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well, the error message kind of explains that `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/` is not the right namespace to be used for XSLT, the right namespace is `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`

Comment: The error tells you everything you need to know. This is not valid XSL. It's not even valid XML (which can only have one root element). The root of your XSL should be: `<xsl:stylesheet>` or `<xsl:transform>` or any other single element of your choice that includes the `xsl:version` attribute. Recommend you simplify your XSL to something that just takes something simple like `<myxml></myxml>` and produces something like `<HTML></HTML>`. Then build outward from there once you understand the basics.

Comment: Hi,I changed the top to be `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">` but now I am getting an error about `Error Top-level element 'SCRIPT' may not have a null namespace URI`. Same with `HTML`, what easy to follow website can I use to fix this?